# generating Form from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and HTML. I am trying to make a form by using Jquery. I want to make a button which will add input fields in the html page. (10 max). Here is something i tried.

HTML FILE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TakeMeHome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/design.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center><form id="details">
      Your Place:<input id="source" type="text"><br><br>
      Friend1:<input id="friend1" type="text"><br><br>
      <div class="friends"></div>
      <div id="button">Add!</div><br><br>

      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS File

```
var j=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#friends').append("friend"+j+"<input type='text' id='friend"+j+"' " );   
    });

});
```

css file

```
#button
{
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
width: 40px;
background-color: red;
font-family: arial;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center; 
color:white;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code will be looks like this:

```
var j=2;
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#friends').append("<input type='text' id='friend"+ j +"'/>");   
});
```

If you need something more difficult. Describe situation more.

Comment: heres the thing. I want to get input from the user. If user wants to add more inputs, he can. Lets say he want to name his friends. So other than just appending, i also need what user entred as variaables. So i need different name for each input feild the user adds. U getting what i am trying to say ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to timofeiMih and his code

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   var j= $("#friends input").length;
   $('#friends').append("<input type='text' id='friend"+ j +"'/>");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if( $("#friends input[type=text]").length <= 10 ){
            var i = $("#friends input[type=text]").length
            $('#friends').append("<label for='friend "+i+"'><input type='text' id='friend"+ i +"'/></label>");
        }else{
            alert("Max Friends Reached")
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2PZnm/) is your code. I modified also some stuff in mark-up, doing how i would do if i were you. 
First I modified your `<div id="button">Add!</div>` to `<a href="#">`
Then I removed all `<br>` tags. Why do you need them while you are using css? Also do not forget to catch all inputs which contains a label inside, of course, a `<label>`;

For all 'friend' inputs you can write their name as array :  `name="friend[]"` so when you will get them in php you will have a return like

```
Array (
  [friend] =>
    Array (
      [0] => a
      [1] => b
      [2] => c
      [3] => d
    )
)
```